# An explanation for the Landauer's principle

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information, computational-physics

Has anyone understood the [Landauer's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle)? What is the current status?

In specific, is there a theoretical derivation of the Landauer's Principle?(not the heuristic one based on Salizard's engine) How does one account for thermodynamic concepts applicable to situations involving measurement? What does it mean to reset the state of the apparatus why is free energy expended in the process?

Comment: The Wikipedia article linked in the question seems to be full of references...

Comment: I looked into some of them, They only have a heuristic understanding. I was hoping there was a more complete explanation.

Comment: Can you edit the question to be more specific? I (and probably many others) understand the principle very well, but rather than try to write an encyclopaedic answer it would be better to know exactly which aspects of it you'd like to understand better.

Comment: @nathaniel updated the question

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512105. It gives a derivation of Landauer's Principle from the two postulates of the Second Law of Thermodynamics, and shows how Landauer's Principle follows from the second postulate.

Comment: It's Szilard's engine not Salizard for anyone wanting to look up the heuristic derivation.