# Foundation of Landauer's principle

Tags: entropy, landauers-principle

I have asked this on CS subsite but since there was no reply yet and the question is also somewhat related to physics, I think it will be appropriate to post here as well.

Landauer's principle states the minimum possible amount of energy required to erase one bit of information is $k T \ln 2$

How is this formula found? In terms of energy and memory unit, what is the processing cost per bit for normal and reverse operations respectively?

Comment: Landauer's original paper is freely available and very readable. https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/lectures/Rotman_Summer_School_2013/thermo_computing_docs/Landauer_1961.pdf

Comment: Crossposted from https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91122

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An explanation for the Landauer's principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43589/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple answer would be: consider a physical system that can be in two states. Its thermodynamic entropy is $k_B \log(2)$ due to this. When you erase the bit, then you have a definite microstate and the entropy is zero. Since entropy cannot decrease it has to go somewhere, and this means it needs to be transferred to the environment that has temperature $T$, giving us a cost $k_B T \log(2)$.

This is the simplified version of a slightly dodgy derivation (note how I facilely equated thermodynamic entropy with information entropy without justification and did not specify how erasure happened or the entropy got moved around). Once can do this more rigorously, [like in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0512105.pdf).

Also, it is worth pointing out it is a misconception that the cost has to be paid in energy. If you have an empty computer memory you can just swap the erased bit for a fresh zero reversibly. But empty computer memory is in a sense a heat reservoir at absolute zero but with very limited capacity (it will eventually run out). It is possible to show that [the cost can be paid using other conserved quantities like spin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5330). It is just that in practice we tend to move entropy around by dumping it as waste heat in a cool outside heat bath.

Comment: @Anders I accepted your post as answer but I wanted to ask, why in concept entropy decreases when you erase the bit? I get it is going to somewhere else but couldn't figure out the relation of clearing bit and decreasing entropy.

Comment: Maybe I need to update the answer to make it clearer. Entropy is a measure (the log) of the number of possible microstates that could make up an observed macrostate. A bit with value X has two possible microstates (log(2)) while a bit set to zero has one possible microstate (log(1)=0).

Comment: "erase" implies, at least to me, an irreverisble process.